# AWS EC2 login attempt failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

We have AWS EC2 instance to which we could able to connect successfully last week. After that no password change no setting change and all of a sudden it is saying the login attempt failed.

Using same ip address, same username and same password which we used last week.
Confirmed by logging into EC2 instance and the password is same.

Also tried by downloading RDP file to connect even that is not working.

Can you please help what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Does it fail quickly, or does it take some time (eg 10-20 seconds) before failing? If the instance was stopped and started, it might have changed IP address. Your own IP address might also have changed (eg at home) so check the Security Group that is associated with the instance (can you add it to your question?). What do you mean by "Confirmed by logging into EC2 instance" -- I thought you said you couldn't login?

Comment: have you configured incoming connections in your Security group? 
have you checked your  public IP address of your ec2 instance?
Try connecting through aws console using ec2 instance connect form browser